# How can I translate this C# variable declaration to something IronPython can handle?

Tags: c#, com, ironpython

I don't know if this is a simple matter of RTFM, but bear with me as it was a while ago I used a statically typed language...

I'm porting some C# code to IronPython, and I just stumbled on this statement below. I'm not at liberty to post the actual code, so I'll write it in pseudo code instead:

`data_type_1 variable_1 = variable_2 as data_type_2;`

where

`variable_2` is a COM object from earlier parts of the code, `variable_1` is a new variable, and `data_type_1` is a class that interacts with the data in the COM object.

What does it mean? I'm guessing it is some form of conversion. How can I convert it to something IronPython can make sense of?

Answer (score 2):

The `as` operator is a "safe cast" operator, it converts the `variable_2` to type `data_type_2`. If that conversion fails, it doesn't throw an exception but returns `null`.

Further, to be able to assign a value of `data_type_2` (the result of the 'as' expression) to a variable of `data_type_1`, that data_type_2 must be derived from data_type_1 (or implement the interface data_type_1).

Comment: Ok, turns out I guessed right. Would you happen to know how to do the same conversion in IronPython?

Comment: @c00kiemonster - sorry, I know only the C# side. I hoped you could translate my explanation into IronPython yourself.

Answer (score 1):

After killing a few hours I figured I might as well do it the simple but perhaps not the prettiest way. I simply downloaded Visual C# 2010 Express (free version) and wrote a minimal Class Library containing one method consisting of only the troublesome statement. I then built the dll, which was promptly imported and used in the original IronPython script.

From idea to a working solution it only took 10 minutes. Kudos to Microsoft, it was a whole lot simpler to build a dll than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans already explained, the `as` operator converts from one type to another. This is necessary to keep C#'s compiler happy. IronPython, on the other hand, doesn't care - you can call whatever operation you need to on `variable_2` and if it doesn't work you'll get an error at runtime.

So, the short version is that `as` is unnecessary in IronPython and that statement can be reduced to

```
variable_1 = variable_2
```

If you do need to check whether a Python object is of a particular type (or a subclass), use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance).

Comment: This particular example was made further difficult with `variable 2` being a nasty COM object that was hard to work with. I am happy though that I went through the issues. Otherwise I would never realized how easy it is to make your own custom C# DLLs. That could come in very handy one day...